# Add git submodule using a specific commit number

Tags: git-submodules

I'm using git submodule commands to add [this FSM repo](https://github.com/tkem/fsmlite) in my project. I want to checkout a specific release commit. By default the master branch is checked out. 
After adding the git repo, when I run

`$ git submodule`

It gives

`d1b66d66cfa95f238a7498465908a262f4b2326a directory_path/fsmlite`

The commit number here belongs to a master branch commit. How can I checkout another commit instead, using its commit number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be some other way to do this, but I got the desired commit by

```
$ cd directory_path/fsmlite 
$ git checkout v0.7.1      (this is the branch I wanted to point to)
$ git submodule update
$ cd parent_dir
$ git submodule 

  +de19ea0a71cb6082fe9311694a27e8f0cc2f972a directory_path/fsmlite (v0.7.1)
```

which is the specific commit number I wanted